# Java XML Parsing - incorrect string version of the data with VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, vtd-xml, kanji

I am parsing an XML document in UTF-8 encoding with Java using VTD-XML.

A small excerpt looks like:

```
<literal></literal>
<literal></literal>
<literal></literal>
```

I want to iterate through each literal and print it out to the console. However, what I get is:

```
¢
```

I am correctly navigating to each element. The way that I get the text value is by calling:

```
private static String toNormalizedString(String name, int val, final VTDNav vn) throws NavException {
    String strValue = null;
    if (val != -1) {
        strValue = vn.toNormalizedString(val);
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

I've also tried `vn.getXPathStringVal();`, however it yields the same results.

I know that each of the literals above aren't just strings of length one. Rather, they seem to be unicode "characters" composed of two characters. I am able to correctly parse and output the kanji characters if they're length is just one.

My question is - how can I correctly parse and output these characters using VTD-XML? Is there a way to get the underlying bytes of the text between the literal tags so that I can parse the bytes myself?

**EDIT**

Code to process each line of the XML - converting it to a byte array and then back to a String.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/sample.xml"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            byte[] myBytes = null;

            try {
                myBytes = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            System.out.println(new String(myBytes));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the XML is correctly converted to `byte[]` representation of a UTF-8 string before you invoked `vtdGen.setDoc(doc)` (or `vtdGen.setDoc_BR(doc)`)? You can also check which encoding VTDNav has currently set via `vtdNav.getEncoding()` and check the returned int value against the constants defined in VTDNav

Comment: @RomanVottner - Yes, I did check that vtdNav.getEncoding() == VTDNav.Format_UTF8 is true. Could you elaborate on how I can check that the XML is correctly converted to a byte[] representation of the UTF-8 string? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622226/check-if-a-string-is-valid-utf-8-encoded-in-java) is helpful. Poor mens solution could be to set a breakpoint right at `vtdGen.setDoc(...)` and then see what you get in return on evaluating something along the line `new String(bytes);` inside your IDE while debugging.

Comment: @RomanVottner I am able to verify that the XML can be correctly converted to a byte[] representation of a UTF-8 string. I used a buffered reader to read the file line by line - converted it to a byte array and then converted it back to a String. The resulting String is the same as the original.

Comment: Not sure if I can help anyfurther on this issue. Maybe file some bug-ticket (or question) to thier issue tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/vtd-xml/bugs/

Comment: get 2.13_4. It supports supplementary chars.

Comment: @Roman Vottner--get 2.13_4 it fixed the supplementary char issue.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author thanks for the effort, if you could make this fix available via Maven central this would be awesome as version 2.13 dates back to June 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to get the string involving characters that is greater than 0x10000. That bug is known and is in the process of being addressed... I will notify you once the fix is out.
This question may be identical to this one...
[Map supplementary Unicode characters to BMP (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808207/map-supplementary-unicode-characters-to-bmp-if-possible)

Comment: thanks for the reply! Yes, it looks like the issue is the same. I used the code from the link that you posted and used the string `` and obtained the same results as the author of that thread (only the lower 16 bits are used). The version of vtd-xml that I'm using is 2.13_2 (the latest I believe). A fix will be very helpful! Thanks!